# MySQL select AND statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database like that:

```
Id | Name
1  | term1
1  | term2
1  | term3
2  | term4
2  | term5
2  | term6
```

I want to select ID that contains term1 AND term3.

Or, for example, term4 AND term5 AND term6.

How can I do that?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Should you read first "[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: Hi. This is *obviously* absolutely basic so please look for it in your textbook and past questions. When you *do* have a question & no answer after a lot of reading & googling, please read & act on the downvot arrow text & [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

To get Ids which must have the names provided as parameters you can use below query which meets the criteria using some aggregation

For term1 & term3

```
select Id
from demo
where Name in ('term1', 'term3')
group by Id
having count(*) = sum(Name in ('term1', 'term3'));
```

For term4 & term5 & term6

```
select Id
from demo
where Name in ('term4', 'term5','term6')
group by Id
having count(*) = sum(Name in ('term4', 'term5','term6'));
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfb92a/7)

Answer (score 0):

Below query would give you all `Id` where `Name` is 'term1'

```
SELECT Id from table where Name in ('term1');
```

To fetch Id having term1 or term3

```
SELECT Id from table where Name in ('term1', 'term3');
```

Comment: I think he wants to get the Id who gets both term1 AND term3

Comment: Updated answer for AND.

Comment: Your last with AND won't return anything

Comment: Hmm @JeanDoux, you are right.. and hence the question asked is wrong. We cannot have `term4 AND term5 AND term6` based on the table structure provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT Id, Count(Distinct Name)
 FROM Table
 WHERE Name in ('term1','term3')
 Group By Id 
 HAVING Count(Distinct Name) > 1
```

I think it's what you want. If you want 3 terms you change the Having ...>2